# $P$ is a moving point on the graph $y = ae^{-x}$ and $A$ and $B$ lie on the axes so that $OAPB$ is a rectangle.

Tags: calculus

The graph of $y = ae^{-x}$ for $a > 0$ is shown. $P$ is a moving point on the graph and $A$ and $B$ lie on the axes as shown so that $OAPB$ is a rectangle.

This question is part of applications of differential calculus and optimisation. i can differentiate the function given ($dy/dx = -ae^{-x}$) but cannot see how this will help to find the co-ordinate of $P$ in terms of $a$ such that the perimeter of the rectangle is minimised. i understand to minimise a quantity you have to find the minimum/maximum of the derivative.

[image: visual description of problem]

Comment: Is the question: "find the coordinates of P in terms of a?". Please elaborate.

Comment: yes, im trying to find the x-coordinate of p in terms of a

Comment: from the figure it seems that $P$ is the point of coordinates $(x, ae^{-x})$, correct? but what is your problem?

Comment: The x-coordinate of P is x.

Comment: @EmilioNovati i've edited the question, i explained it poorly.

Answer (score 1):

The perimeter of the rectangle is given by:
$$ 2(|x_P| + |y_P|) $$
Where $(x_P, y_P)$ are the coordinates of the point. Since we know the function that binds the two coordinates, we assign:
$$ x_P = x $$
$$ y_P = f(x) = ae^{-x} $$
Then the "perimeter function" becomes:
$$ P(x) = 2(|x_P| + |y_P|) = 2(|x| + ae^{-x}) $$
As you have correctly stated, to find the extreme points we need to find the derivative's roots.
However, this is not *completely* true, because you may find maxima and minima where Fermat's Theorem does not apply. But let's do this in order.
$$ \frac{d}{dx}P(x) = 2(sgn(x) -a{e^{-x}}) $$
Where $sgn(x)$ is a function that gives $-1$ if $x$ is negative, and $1$ if it is positive. (called "sign of x")
And this is how you set up the right derivative. You can go from this to find the roots and apply Fermat's theorem.
You'll also need to analyze wherever the function is not differentiable - i.e where the derivative does not exist. In this particular case, is exists at all points except zero.

If you feel confident already, do not read any further.

To find the roots:
$$ \frac{d}{dx}P(x) = 0 $$
$$ 2(sgn(x) - ae^{-x}) = 0 $$
$$ sgn(x) = ae^{-x} $$
Since we know that $sgn(x)$ only yields positive or negative unity, we can look for these two solutions for x:
$$ \frac1a = \frac1{e^x} $$
$$ -\frac1a = \frac1{e^x} $$
The first has solution $x=\log{a}$, the second has no solution since we're assuming $a > 0$.
You should also check what happens if you try to differentiate in a neighborhood of zero. In this case, you don't find a new extreme point.
The only point of maximum/minimum is then $\log{a}$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

We have $P=(x,ae^{-x})$ so the perimeter of the rectangle (for $x>0$ as in the figure) is
$$
p(a,x)=2(x+ae^{-x})
$$

that is a linear function of $a$, so, for not negative $a$ (as in your figure), it has a minimum for $a=0$

If you want to minimize with respect to $x$ the derivative is $p'(x)=2(1-ae^{-x})$ .

Comment: thanks so much! i've expanded and solved for when the function 2(x + ae^-x) is 0 which turned out to minimise the perimeter of the rectangle. i just want to clarify with your second statement that the perimeter of the rectangle OAPB. i understand p(a,x) = 2(x+ae^-x) because x is the length from origin to point a, and ae^-x is just the y-value of the function at any point (point B)? then we multiply the sum of these by two because there are 2 pairs of similar sides in the rectangle?

Comment: Yes, the coordinates of $P$ are the basis and height of the rectangle.

Answer (score 0):

$$ p = 2 ( x+y) = 2 ( x + a \, e^{-x})$$

which is *constant*

Differentiate

$$ 2 ( 1-a\, e^{-x})= 0 \rightarrow x= \log_e a =\ln a.$$

Comment: thanks for the help on the answer. i think 1-ae^-x = 0 simplifies down to x = ln a though.

Comment: Yes that is what I mean, ..to base $e$

Comment: aah i see. thank you!